# How to create multiple stored procedures from .sql files

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have about 100 stored procedures files that I want to add to a new database that I created. Is there any way I can just drop them in a folder to import them? When I tried that, like how you would with windows explorer, it just opened them all in query windows.

I am using SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: Are they in an existing database or they are just text files on your system?

Comment: why not just concat them using `copy /b file1.sql+file2.sql+file3.sql+file4.sql bigfile.sql` and then import the `bigfile.sql`?

Comment: or better yet, I can write a program that can do this for you from a folder into a bigfile.sql

Comment: Where do I import it to? I am new at sql management.

Comment: You can use the script database option, choose your stored procedures and save them on a sql file

Comment: They are in .sql files. I just have a bunch of them that I want to put into another database. But I dont have the original database I grabbed them from, I just have the 100's of files.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Right now you did not respond to the question in the comments to make your question clearer, but I have these two suggestions

Assuming you already have a database that uses these procedures:

1. Right click the database in Management Studio and click on Task
2. Click on Generate Scripts
3. In the dialog that comes up, click next as you specify the right options
4. Select the checkbox for "Stored Procedures"
5. Select All the required stored procedures
6. Select option to generate script to a new window or file
7. You are done. Run you script on the other database

If you have access to Visual Studio

1. Create a new SQL Server Database project
2. Select the connection string of your new database
3. Create a stored procedure folder and add all the stored procedure files from your system to it
4. Right click the project and click Deploy/Publish

Hope you have the tables referenced in the stored procedures

Comment: I didn't know that the stored procedure files are files to create the stored procedures. I thought that they only contained what the stored procedure does. Thanks.